# Getting events when Button object is released

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

On Windows 7 Phone, using Silverlight framework
I'd like to handle when a Button is released.

It's easy to tell when the button is pressed (Click event which is fired either when pressed or when released according to the ClickMode property)

I've played with all the other events provided with the Events editor (KeyUp, LostFocus, MouseLeave etc..)

But I'm yet to find something that is definitive in regards to getting an event when a button is released.

Ultimately, I'm trying to handle doing a click vs a long click when pressing on a button

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't setting `ClickMode="Release"` work? That is supposed to fire when the button is released.

Comment: It would... But to handle my case, I need to know when the button is clicked *and* when the button is released..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your situation, KeyUp is only half of the story. You also need to handle KeyDown where you will save the current time which you will then compare to the current time value after KeyUp to determine whether the press was short or long. You also need to make sure that you track one particular key in case your handler(s) is/are intercepting all key strokes.

If for some reason ClickDown/Up don't work out you could try handling the Click event but starting with a [ClickMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.clickmode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) of press, then changing ClickMode to release on the press handler. This process, though not simple, would give you a chance to implement the down-hold and timer-release sequence that you're looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither KeyUp nor KeyDown are actually working. None of those events seem to be raised when you click on a button in Windows Phone 7. Can you change the clickmode half-way while being clicked? I guess this would do

Comment: Changing the ClickMode while the button is pressed allows me to receive an even for both click and release.. Thank you for the suggestion...